# ag-Grid: extend rows till right edge if columns don't occupy full width

Tags: ag-grid

In ag-Grid, if the columns occupy a smaller space than the width of the grid, a blank hole appears on the right of the last column. Please see below (example taken from [ag-Grid docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/#resizing-example)):

[image]

The UX designers on my team don't like that. They would like to see the rows extended all the way to the right to balance out the look. Is this possible to do with ag-Grid?

**Edit**: We don't want to use the `sizeColumnsToFit` option, because on large monitors it produces very wide columns and the grid becomes unreadable. We want to use the `autoSize` option to compact the columns and fill the hole on the RHS with blank stripes as suggested above.

Comment: May I know what you did for this issue in the end?

Answer (score 4):

This works like [Craig Weston's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71438591/16886052) but without the need for `!important`:

```
.ag-center-cols-container {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation and resolved with the following css override:

```
.ag-center-cols-container {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: How this is not on by default is beyond my comprehension. Tables look so ugly otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can call the `sizeColumnsToFit` function on the ag-Grid `api` which will fill out the width of the table with the columns.

Take a look at [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/column-sizing/#example-column-resizing).

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Be8sgal6rUfWg8nH) is a plunker example.

**EDIT**
Use the property `suppressSizeToFit` and set it to true to when you call `sizeColumnsToFit`, it won't have an affect. Apply this property to the `defaultColDef` and set it to false for the last column. This was, when you call `sizeColumnsToFit`, only the last column will be set to full width. See the updated plunker above.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear enough - I will edit it. We don't want `sizeColumnsToFit` because on large monitors it produces very wide columns and the grid becomes unreadable. In fact, we want to auto-size the columns and fill the hole on the RHS with blank stripes as suggested in the question.

Comment: That's indeed a very creative solution, Viq. It does however force us to specify max widths on each column, which is difficult to get right and looses the flexibility that auto-size offers. I will run it by our designers. In the meanwhile, other options are welcome. (I wonder if ag-Grid team would consider this a worthy enhancement.)

Comment: Hi Vic, thanks again for the updated plunker. However, I don't think it solves the issue in a realistic use case. Here's [your updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/AGshOZyjCsIOGwsI), the only change is that it has 10 columns instead of 2. This works for wide screens (i.e. extends the last column), however for narrow screens we have lost the size to fit functionality completely. I got slightly better results with Auto Size followed by Size To Fit of last column (see [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/viUUT8zrMOKppF3a)), but even then the last column gets squished on small widths.

Comment: I still think a better solution would be to render the rows from left to right, covering the entire width of the grid and then drawing the columns on top of it. This way both size-to-fit and auto-size solutions would work as they do today and we won't loose their intended behavior by forcing tricky size-to-fit options.

Answer (score 1):

this is how i do it:

```
/**
 * if there is "dead space" present on the grid, the columns will be auto sized to fill the gap
 * @param gridApi
 * @param columnApi
 */
resizeColumnsToFit(gridApi: GridApi, columnApi: ColumnApi, allowShrink = false) {
  if (allowShrink) {
    gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
  } else {
    const gridBodyWidth = document.getElementsByClassName("ag-root-wrapper")[0].clientWidth; // todo: use grid's id instead of [0] to allow multiple grids on a page
    const allColumnsWidth = columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns().map(c => c.getActualWidth()).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    if (gridBodyWidth > allColumnsWidth) {
      gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }
  }
}
```

This method will size columns to fit only when there is "dead" space on the right. Optionaly set allowShrink to true to force resizing even if there is no dead space

Answer (score 0):

One possible option I've been playing with is adding a fake column at the end to fill the remaining space. To do so, you just need to add a column with options similar to the following to the end of your list of columns:

```
{
  flex: 1,
  headerName: '',
}
```

See [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/C9XycYDvjAOqr83u) forked from @ViqMontana's example above.

It's not a perfect solution, but wanted to mention it here in case it helps.

Comment: Thank you, @JKillian. I think this is a good workaround. I believe I had tried it myself but there was some nuance because of which we did not go with this approach. Good to document it here though.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding [Craig Weston's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71438591/3403247) to also work for pinned bottom rows:

```css
.ag-center-cols-container, .ag-floating-bottom-container {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Or, without `!important` (thanks to [Olga Isakova's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71719404/3403247)):

```css
.ag-center-cols-container, .ag-floating-bottom-container {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply flex property to make the last column wider in case there is free space. Please see [the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-sizing/#column-flex).

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/q4nTusm9PG3kuYMe?open=main.js) is a small example based on the code snipped from the question:

```
const columnDefs = [
  { field: 'athlete', width: 150, suppressSizeToFit: true },
  {
    field: 'age',
    headerName: 'Age of Athlete',
    width: 90,
    minWidth: 50,
    flex: 1
  },
];
```